# Static Check Input Parameter is Allowed

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

For this code piece:

```cpp
constexpr string_view nameOk[] = {"name1", "name2");

class Bar {
public:
  void foo(const string& name);
};

...
Bar bar;
bar.foo("name1");  // OK
bar.foo("name2");  // OK
bar.foo("name3");  // NOT OK
```

Are there any ways to check the input parameter at compile time?

Comment: Um... how could you? A user isn't required to give this function a compile-time value.

Comment: You can do this in C++20 with consteval: https://godbolt.org/z/veqjfqE83

Comment: consteval sounds great, however my code base is still on c++17 for now.

Comment: but I think I could do something similar to consteval in c++17 with macro.